# Axis ticks truncated when using GraphicsRow

Tags: plotting, ticks

The bottom part of my axis ticks are truncated below, what is right padding option to make them show up properly?

```
cylinder[t_] := 
  With[{x = Cos[t], y = Sin[t]}, 
   Graphics3D@Cylinder[{{x, y, 0}, {x, y, x^2 + 3 y^2}}, 1/100]];
plot3da = 
  Plot3D[{0, x^2 + 3 y^2}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 <= 1], 
   MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5], PlotPoints -> 50];
plot3d[t_] := Show[plot3da, cylinder[t]]
blue = ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[1]];
plot2da = 
  Plot[{Callout[Cos[t]^2 + 3 Sin[t]^2, 
     "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Lambda]\), \(1\)]\)", Above], 
    Callout[Cos[t]^2 + 3 Sin[t]^2, 
     "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Lambda]\), \(2\)]\)", Below], 
    Callout[2, "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Lambda]\), \(ave\)]\)", 
     Above]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {blue, blue, Dashed}, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}];
point[t_] := 
 ListPlot[With[{x = Cos[t], y = Sin[t]}, {{t, x^2 + 3 y^2}}], 
  PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large], Filling -> Axis, 
  FillingStyle -> Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.8]]]
plot2d[t_] := Show[plot2da, point[t], ImageSize -> 400];
plotCombined[t_] := 
 GraphicsRow[{Show[plot3d[t], ImageSize -> 600], 
   Show[plot2d[t], ImageSize -> 500]}]
plotCombined[0]
```

[image]

Comment: For me (12.1.1 for Linux x86, 64 bit) the ticks appear ok.

Comment: `plotCombined[t_] := 
 GraphicsRow[{Show[plot3d[t], ImageSize -> 600], 
   Show[plot2d[t], ImageSize -> 500, 
    PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.1]]}]`

Comment: @cvgmt hm, if I do this, the lambda_1 callout is truncated

Comment: @demm I  did 12.1.0 on Macos, but same problem on 12.3.0 on Linux -- https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/f5733b22-d087-4b13-84a2-7fc93a02a0f9

Comment: `GraphicsRow[{Show[plot3d[t], ImageSize -> 600], 
   Show[plot2d[t], ImageSize -> 500, ImagePadding->Scaled[.005]]}]`?

Comment: aha, ImagePadding is the correct option here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the option [`ImagePadding`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImagePadding.html) in the second `Show` in definition of `plotCombined`:

```
plotCombined[t_] := GraphicsRow[{Show[plot3d[t], ImageSize -> 600], 
      Show[plot2d[t], ImageSize -> 500, ImagePadding -> Scaled[.005]]}]

plotCombined[0]
```

[image]